# Select from Access Database where number is equal to

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access, int

I am having some difficulty selecting items from an Access database where the number is equal to zero. Below is the code that i have, i keep getting a datatype error. On Access i have my NumScore as a Long Integer. I've gone back and forth between double and no success. Thanks for the help.

```
        int Num= 0;

        con.Open();

        cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select Inc, Reviewed from upload Where NumScore='" + Num + "'", con);
        da3 = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

        da3.Fill(dt3);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt3;
        con.Close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put your variable Num between single quotes. This transforms your `Num` in a string. So removing the quotes could be a solution.
But you should really use a parameterized query

```
   cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"Select Inc, Reviewed from upload 
                           Where NumScore=@v", con);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v", Num);
   da3 = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
```

In this way the database engine receives a Numeric parameter and will handle it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The single apostrophes are causing your number to be seen as a string literal. Remove them:

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select Inc, Reviewed from upload Where NumScore=" + Num, con);
```

Also, you should really look at parameterizing your query, for security and so you don't run into typos like this one.